# Alarm Manager does not work in background

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I used alarm manager in my program,but for the first time I run it, It just worked when  my program was open and when it was close it did not work in the background, but in the second time it worked in the background too.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlertReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+60000, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

AlertReceiver :

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("Log", "onReceiver!!");
   
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.yadame">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".AlertReceiver"/>

</application>
```

Comment: In which android version you are testing this?

Comment: I tested on Android 6